# If C and D are club sets, why is the intersection of C and D closed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Almost every proof I've seen on club (closed and unbounded) sets begins with

If C and D are club sets then it is easy to see why C intersect D are closed. Intuitively it makes sense, but I haven't been able to construct a proper argument explaining why. If you had to explain to somebody why C intersect D are closed, how might you do it?

Comment: That the sets $C$ and $D$ are unbounded (as well as closed) is irrelevant; the intersection of an arbitrary collection of closed sets (whether bounded or not) is closed. This is a basic property of closed sets in any topological space; the order topology of a well-ordered set is no exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does it means when $C$ is closed? It means that if $\sup(C\cap\alpha)=\alpha$, then $\alpha\in C$. This should make the proof that $C\cap D$ is closed far easier to see for yourself.

The harder part is to show the intersection is unbounded, for this pick $\alpha$, and start constructing a sequence above $\alpha$, whose odd indexed elements are from $C$ and even elements are from $D$, what can you say about the supremum of this sequence?

Comment: Ahh thanks I got it now. If C is unbounded and sup(C∩α)=α then sup(D∩α) must equal α as well so sup((C∩D)∩α)=α and α∈C∩D. And the supremum of this sequence must be in both sets, hence C∩D is unbounded!